# Убрать свойство disabled

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Есть 2 `button`, одна со свойством `disabled`, а вторая - нет. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на вторую кнопку свойство `disabled` у первой исчезало.

```
<button disabled id="btn1"></button>
<button id="btn2"></button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто ставите свойство `disabled` в `false`:

```js
document.querySelector('#btn2').addEventListener('click', e => document.querySelector('#btn1').disabled  = false);
```

```html
<button disabled id="btn1">Btn</button>
<button id="btn2">OK</button>
```

Comment: Ваш код почему-то не работает.

Comment: @A.Hall, вероятно, у Вас просто старый браузер.

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, моя ошибка.